# Multiple labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a plot and I want the first item that I plot to have a label that is partly a string and partly element 0 of array "t". I tried setting the variable the_initial_state equal to a string:

```
the_initial_state = str('the initial state')
```

And the plotting as follows:

```
plt.figure(5) 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=1000)
plt.rc("font", size=10)
plt.title("Time-Dependent Probability Density Function")  
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(0,0.8)
plt.plot(x,U,'k--')
**plt.plot(x,Pd[0],'r',label= the_initial_state, label =t[0])** 
plt.plot(x,Pd[1],'m',label=t[1])
plt.plot(x,Pd[50],'g',label=t[50])
plt.plot(x,Pd[100],'c',label=t[100])
plt.legend(title = "time", bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.9), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

But I receive an "invalid syntax" error for the line that is  indicated by ** **.

Is there any way to have a label that contains a string and an element of an array to a fixed number of decimal places?

Comment: Here you are trying to give the label twice, cant you append the value into a single string and then assign it to the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'the initial state'` already is a string, so you do not need to cast it again.

I do not see a syntax error for the moment, but surely you cannot set the label twice.

Concattenating a string and a float in python can e.g. be done using the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) function.

```
the_initial_state = 'the initial state {}'.format(t[0])
plt.plot(x,Pd[0],'r',label= the_initial_state)
```

should work.

There is a [nice page](https://pyformat.info) outside explaining the format syntax. For example, to format the  float `2.345672` to 2 decimal places, use
`"{:.2f}".format(2.345672)`

Comment: is it also possible to change the number of decimal places of t[0] within that format function?